# How to update data on database when I click an actionlink more than one time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have two models. One is `Trip.cs` and the other is `TripReservation.cs`. I have a method called `ReserveTrip` as below:

```
public ActionResult ReserveTrip(int id)
        {
            Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
            var trip = _db.Trip.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);            
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            if(trip == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                reservation.TripId = id;
                reservation.UserId = userId;
                reservation.NumberOfSeatsAvailable -= 1;
                reservation.NumberOfReservations += 1;
                _db.Reservation.Add(reservation);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("MyReservations");
            }
        }
```

`Trip.cs`:

```
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Destination {get; set;}
public DateTime DepartureDate {get; set;}
public string MeetPlace {get; set;}

public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
```

`ReservationTrip.cs`:

```
public int ReservationTripId {get; set;}
public int TripId {get; set;} //foreign key
public string UserId {get; set;} //foreign key
public int NumberOfSeatsAvailable {get; set;}
public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

This method saves the data of the trip where the user reserves when he clicks on the actionlink named "Reserve Trip" on the table of TripReservation and redirects the user to another action called "MyReservations" which displays all the trips that user reserves. Everything works very well but the problem is that every time the user clicks on that ActionLink called "ReserveTrip" that trip is displayed multiple times. And the property NumberOfReservations doesn't increase with 1.
The actionlink is displayed in every trip on the index view.
The actionlink code is: `@Html.ActionLink("Reserve Trip","ReserveTrip","Trip", new { id = m.Id}, new { @class="btn btn-info"})`
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Reservation reservation = new Reservation(); your reservation is not from the database

Comment: Should I do something like this: var rezervation = _db.Reservations.SingleorDefault(m => m.TripId == id) ?